# Simulated width view of viewcontroller container less than embedded tableview controller width

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In the Xcode Interface Builder (IB), I have created:

1. standard ViewController (VC); and
2. TableViewController (TVC).

I'm working with 4.7 inch screen size (375 x 667 points) for both VC and TVC.

In the VC, I have status bar (20 points) and toolbar (44 points) at top of screen. I 'dragged-in' a container (375 x 603 points) to fill the balance of the VC space (also using the IB).

I embedded a separate TVC in the said container and then added a table list to the TVC which I populated with several sections and respective cells.

In these respective cells, I have added some text labels and images.

The TVC and container in the VC are of the same width according to IB, but when I run the project in a simulator and my iPhone to test, the width of the **visible** tableview in my VC is 'shorter' than the actual TVC's contents.

In simple words, I am missing the 'right hand part' of the content of every cell in the table view.

How can I amend my alignments such that 100% width of each call in my table view shows up in the container and therefore in my VC and actual view?

*Note: I embedded my TVC into the container of a VC because I wanted the table view to use static cells and not dynamic cells.*

Comment: You can still use static cells with just a regular table view. No need to overcomplicate it with containers and a table view controller.

Comment: This is true. But I want to use a UIViewController because I want the TableView to form only part of the view controller. I have text labels and a nav bar to include also.

Comment: All you have to do is either set the constraints (Auto Layout) or set the frame (non-Auto Layout) of the table view to make it shorter and have room for other elements.

Comment: I'd rather not disable auto layout. I have various icons throughout my respective VCs and all are already set to relative size classes.

Comment: You don't have to disable auto layout. Simply modify the table view's constraints to make it shorter.

Comment: I set the mode of the container to 'aspect width' and it seems to solve the problem. Everything scaled horizontal perfectly now to fit.

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking this.

I solved my problem by simply setting the mode of the container to 'aspect width' (in the Xcode IB) and it seems to solve the problem.

Everything scaled horizontally (and vertically) perfectly now to fit whatever content is in my embedded TVC.